# How to set JsonProperty value dynamically

Tags: java, json

I want to create a json request like below:

```
"additionalData": {
"riskdata.basket.item1.sku": "045155",
"riskdata.basket.item1.quantity": "1"
"riskdata.basket.item2.sku": "0451166",
"riskdata.basket.item2.quantity": "1"

...

"riskdata.basket.item4.sku": "0451111",
"riskdata.basket.item4.quantity": "2"
```

Please suggest how to set the JsonProperty value dynamically in the object mapping.

Example: deliveryMethod is a constant field hence I am able to map like below using JsonProperty annotation. However, how I can use the JsonProperty for sku and quantity  so that it will accept as many number as possible. Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
public class AdditionalData implements java.io.Serializable
{
    @JsonProperty(value = "riskdata.deliveryMethod")
    private String deliveryMethod;
    @JsonProperty(value = "riskdata.basket.item??.sku")
    private String sku;
    @JsonProperty(value = "riskdata.basket.item??.quantity")
    private String quantity;
}
```

Comment: That's not the ideal way to structure your data in json in the first place.
You should ideally be using array objects.

Comment: Thank you!. I know this is not the ideal way for structuring the json; however this will be accepted by a 3rd party application who asked us to send this specific format. Hence, any help would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, then the only other way I assume is to customize ObjectMapper (write your own) and use it to custom convert your objects to json.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `basket[]` array property in your `AdditionalData`class.

```
public class AdditionalData implements java.io.Serializable
{
  @JsonProperty(value = "riskdata.deliveryMethod")
  private String deliveryMethod;

  @JsonProperty(value = "riskdata.basket")
  private Basket[] basket;
}

public class Basket implements java.io.Serializable
{
  @JsonProperty(value = "sku")
  private String sku;

  @JsonProperty(value = "quantity")
  private String quantity;
}
```

And the change your json structure like this:

```
"additionalData": {
  "riskdata.basket": [
   {
      "sku": "045155",
      "quantity": 1"
   },
   {
      "sku": "045156",
      "quantity": 1"
   }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details. Unfortunately, the json structure can not be changed as this will be consumed by a 3rd party application. They are asking us to send the json data in the structure which I mentioned. Initially, I implemented the array approach. Is there any other way to achieve this keeping the json structure same. This is very critical to me.